# Translating curl into CakePHP 3.6 httpclient?

Tags: php, curl, cakephp

I am working with BShaffer OAuth2/CakePHP 3.6 and most of the way there. However, I've hit a minor stumbling block in the code and I'm currently attempting to translate a PHP Curl command into a Cake friendly httpClient command

The curl command in question is

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

while my current attempt for the code is

```
$http = new Client();

$auth = [
    '_csrfToken' => $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken'),
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'username' => $result->UserID,
    'password' => $createCode
];

$response = $http->post('/oauth/request', $auth);
```

I have a feeling I need to put username/password into an auth header for OAuth2, but I'm not 100% sure on how to do so. The documentation for the httpClient does include OAuth2, but as a single header:

```
$http = new Client([
'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken]
]);
$response = $http->get('https://example.com/api/profile/1');
```

EDIT:

With the examples from the comments, I've gotten PHP's CURL working directly, however Cake's Client is still producing a blank result. This is what I have at the moment:

```
$data = $this->request->getData();

$result = $this->Users->RegisterNewUser($data);
$report = $data['email'];

if ($result->result == 1)
{
    $generatePrivateKey = $this->OAuth->generatePrivateKey($result->UserID);


    $query = [
        'client_id' => $result->UserID,
        'client_secret' => $generatePrivateKey,
        'redirect_uri' => ''
    ];
    $this->OAuth->insertClientData($query);


// Insert User into clients //
    $auth = [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    ];
    // Is not working //
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->post('https://example.com/oauth/request', $auth, [
      'auth' => ['username' => $result->UserID, 'password' => 
$generatePrivateKey]
    ]);
    print_r($response->getBody());

    // Works //
    $ch = curl_init('https://example.com/oauth/request');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $result->UserID . ":". $generatePrivateKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
}
```

Comment: If you're using OAUTH your access token is your "username and password", you usually have to generate an API key

Comment: That's the point that I am currently at - generating the key. According to the documentation, the auth request needs to be passed as a post

Comment: Do you have your access token?

Comment: Generated on registration, and set up in client table.

Comment: I am not using an existing Cake library. I am integrating Bshaffer OAuth2 directly into my application for API authentication so user registration is custom. I am currently following https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/

Comment: Yea I wrote the reply in generic PHP so it should work regardless

Comment: You are missing a step here, don't you? The Curl request that you are showing uses Basic authentication, and AFAICT it's used to retrieve a token for an oAuth authenticated request at a later point.

Comment: At the moment I'm following the cookbook and testing to make sure the setup works. I am attempting to access the token controller I wrote based off this example, via the POST request - the user client/secret has been created, and in this example is the username/password.

Comment: So what you should do is issuing a request that uses [**Basic authentication**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#using-basic-authentication), as that is what the Curl request is doing.

Comment: Interestingly enough, @MasonStedman 's curl example works with an edit of CURLOPT_USERPWD - I get back the key as it should be returned. However, Cake's httpClient ->post returns a blank page, even with basic auth.

Comment: You're getting an empty reply (not failed login etc?)

Comment: Empty reply. Code 200 (OK), null JSON, null XML. As far as I can tell, the two are almost essentially the same requests. The proper response back is a JSON string with the key, bearer, and timeout.

Comment: I can run it either way - I would prefer to use Cake's native response to this though, but if php_curl works, it works.

Comment: How do you determine that it's empty?

Comment: Console network view, examining the response back directly - as well as attempting Cake's tools such as $response->getBody()

Comment: Then there's probably still something wrong with your request, hard to tell without seeing what exactly you are doing. I just gave it a go with the linked guide, and it works fine.

Comment: I edited my question with the current code and examples showing what's happening during registration

Comment: You cannot use `print_r` to dump the content of a stream, you'd have to either cast it to a string (`(string)$response->getBody()`), or access the content directly (`$response->getBody()->getContents()`).

Comment: That did the job, thank you! I've got a proper key I can access now as well as being able to work out the others I need. Can you make this an answer?

Comment: Sure... btw, the fact that the library seems to ship with plain text secret handling (storage and validation) is pretty alarming, that should be an absolute no go!

Comment: @ndm Which PHP library would you recommend? It's really another question, and last comment I'll post for this here, but I am open to all options.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with all the OAuth server side libraries out there, I've only ever used **https://oauth2.thephpleague.com**, where you have to implement repository providers (clients/users/etc) yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to issue a request that uses Basic authentication, that's what the shown Curl request does.

To do so, specify the `username` and `password` keys in the `auth` option, which is to be passed in the third argument of the clients `post()` method:

```
$http = new Client();

$data = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
];

$options = [
    'auth' => [
        'username' => $result->UserID,
        'password' => $createCode
    ]
];

$response = $http->post('/oauth/request', $data, $options);
```

The response body can then for example be retrieved via the response `body()` method, the streams `getContents()` method, or even via magic properties (not a fan of them) that parse the data accordingly:

```
$stringBody = $reponse->body();
$stringBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$arrayData = $response->json;
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Http Client > Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#authentication)**
- **[Cookbook > Http Client > Reading Response Bodies](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#reading-response-bodies)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a starting point, it should work for most cURL scenarios that you need an auth token:

```
        $post_data = ["stuff" => $stuff, "stuff2" => $stuff2];

        $data_string = json_encode($post_data);
        $ch = curl_init('https://endpoint.com');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $your_auth_token,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        // Do stuff with output
```

Comment: My guess is that client_id:client_secret would become the $auth_token?

Comment: Likely, this is standard format for using token auth \ curl so assuming you have the correct token (client secret seems likely) it should pass the post on correctly.  do a print_r on the output and it'll tell you what the gateway said back.